# MySQL data directory stays default with -v flag in docker image

Tags: mysql, docker, mysqlbinlog

I am trying to start MySQL using docker image, I wanted to have a look at the binlog files, however I couldn't find them in `/var/lib/mysql`. From a few stackoverflow and Google reads, potential reason could be that mysql doesn't have permissions to write in /var/lib/mysql. 
So I tried providing a different path using -v flag while starting the docker using the command `docker run -it --rm --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debezium -e MYSQL_USER=mysqluser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw -v /home/username/mysql debezium/example-mysql:1.1`  
However, even after this, datadir variable in client still remains /var/lib/mysql. Can someone help me in this? 
Using `docker run -it --rm --name mysqlterm --link mysql --rm mysql:5.7 sh -c 'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"` to start the MySQL client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running client on different container and expect yo find logs there?
if you want see log files, you should run `docker exec mysql bash`, sometimes bash is not available, then use `sh`.

Comment: It's a different container, but it links with the first container using `--link mysql`

Comment: I tried `docker exec mysql ls /home/username/mysql`, but still can't see logs there

Comment: oh `docker exec mysql ls /var/lib/mysql` is showing the desired log files :D

Comment: Noob Docker user here.